# HTTP_STATUS in io.opentracing.tag is setting to string value

Tags: java, spring, vert.x, opentracing

I am using `io.opentracing` to get the trace and log it.
But, getting duplicate trace. One with `http.status_code` as string and other as integer

Example trace:

```
{
tags:
{
"http.url":"http://localhost:8080",
"http.status_code" : "200",
"http.method":"POST"
}
}
```

and

```
{
tags:
{
"http.url":"http://localhost:8080",

"http.status_code" : 200,

"http.method":"POST"
}
}
```

Expected output

```
{
tags:
{
"http.url":"http://localhost:8080",

"http.status_code" : 200,

"http.method":"POST"
}
}
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the TracingPolicy to IGNORE solves the issue.